# Bug after sign apk

Tags: android, proguard, android-contacts, contactscontract

I made a Contact App using Batch Operation like below

```
final public class BatchOperation {
private final String TAG = "BatchOperation";
private final ContentResolver mResolver;
// List for storing the batch mOperations
private final ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> mOperations;

public BatchOperation(Context context, ContentResolver resolver) {
    mResolver = resolver;
    mOperations = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
}

public int size() {
    return mOperations.size();
}

public void add(ContentProviderOperation cpo) {
    mOperations.add(cpo);
}

public Uri execute() {
    Uri result = null;

    if (mOperations.size() == 0) {
        return result;
    }
    // Apply the mOperations to the content provider
    try {
        ContentProviderResult[] results = mResolver.applyBatch(
                ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, mOperations);
        if ((results != null) && (results.length > 0))
            result = results[0].uri;
    } catch (final OperationApplicationException e1) {
        Log.e(TAG, "storing contact data failed", e1);
    } catch (final RemoteException e2) {
        Log.e(TAG, "storing contact data failed", e2);
    }
    mOperations.clear();
    return result;
}
```

Everything work fine in **debug mode** but after I signed my app in **release mode** I face this problem

```
E/BatchOperation﹕ storing contact data failed
java.lang.ClassCastException: a cannot be cast to android.content.ContentProviderOperation
        at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.applyBatch(ContentProviderNative.java:479)
        at android.content.ContentProviderClient.applyBatch(ContentProviderClient.java:227)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.applyBatch(ContentResolver.java:951)
```

in this line

```
ContentProviderResult[] results = mResolver.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY,
                mOperations);
```

Here are my proguard file

```
-optimizationpasses 5 
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-dump class_files.txt
-printseeds seeds.txt
-printusage unused.txt
-printmapping mapping.txt
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*
-allowaccessmodification
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-repackageclasses ''


-dontwarn com.actionbarsherlock.**
-dontwarn org.apache.**
-dontwarn com.commonsware.**
-dontwarn freemarker.**
-dontwarn ezvcard.**

-keep class org.apache.** { *; }
-keep class android.support.v4.app.** { *; } 
-keep class com.actionbarsherlock.** { *; }
-keep class ezvcard.** { *; }
-keep class com.fasterxml.jackson.** { *; }
```

Thank for your reading,

Answer (score 1):

When this kind of things happen I always ask a question to my fellow developers... Are you using Proguard?
Try disabling Proguard and compiling into release mode for testing. Also remove optimization by using

```
-dontoptimize
```

Also check that your Content Provider is being kept with something like

```
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
```

Comment: Yes, after disable proguard everything is fine again ,

Comment: Try without the optimization option. I don't use it anymore 'cause its a bit of a trouble maker.

Comment: I recommend you to use the default proguard script that comes with the sdk. It will save you a lot of time.

Comment: I experience the same problem. I need to import contacts and calendar events from android. It works in debug mode but the app crash in release mode.
-dontoptimize
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
I added those lines in project.properties but the app still crashes. Able to share with me the solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Ah , I find out that Proguard obfuscator `android.content.ContentProviderOperation;` class. 
Just add this  `-keep class android.content.** { *; }` everything work fine =)